# How can you make a two-dimensional product table array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to figure out the right way to make a two-dimensional array in java that outputs an N by N square product table where whatever integer the user inputs will be shown in the product table result. I can't seem to figure out how to get the N variable to alter the size and results inside the array. I forgot to upload my own code so I'll add it just to show what I've already did...

```
        int[][] productTable = new int[n][n];
        for (int index = 1; index < n; index++) {
            for (int column =1; column < n; column++) {
                //What now??
            }
        }
        // print format for 2D arrays
        for (int row =0; row < productTable.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < productTable[row].length; col++)
                System.out.printf("%7d", productTable[row][col]);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

[This is what it should look like if you entered in 4 for N](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG1xq.png)

[image]

Comment: Make an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to initialize a two-dimensional array using the `new int[numRows][numCols]` syntax. Then, use a nested loop to iterate through each row and column, filling each slot with the multiplication of the row and column indexes.

```
public static int[][] makeSquareMultiplicationTable(int sideLength) {
    int[][] table = new int[sideLength][sideLength];
    for (int row = 1; row <= sideLength; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= sideLength; col++) {
            table[row-1][col-1] = row * col;
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked well and seeing it laid out like this helped me better understand 2D arrays. I'm still learning Java so there's a lot I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

hope this works :)

```
final int N = 4;
int[][] matrix = new int[N][N];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
        matrix[i][j] = (i+1)*(j+1);
    }
}
```